TypeError: $fotoramaElement.fotorama is not a function
Basically, product images doesn't getting load, it loads after page refresh. and i got this error.
i am using Codazon Theme, i have tried following solution to resolve this issue but it didn't work
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/requirejs-config.js
var config = {
    paths: {
        'fotorama/fotorama': 'fotorama/fotorama',
        'mage/gallery/gallery': 'mage/gallery/gallery'
    },
    shim: {
        'fotorama/fotorama': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'mage/gallery/gallery': {
            deps: ['fotorama/fotorama']
        }
    }
}


Is there any expert who can help us with fixing this problem.
I am also facing the same problem and this is inconsistence, If reloading the page this error sometimes come and sometimes not.

When I face last time jquery was loading twice in frontend, please check if it is same in your case

Also Please check with jquery conflict issue. I was facing same issue before but after upgrading jquery version its resolved.
